# Java and Mysql Update all Records using Arraylist

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I was try to run the program all record updated to display on that program but no change in mysql.

```
    try 
    {
        User user = new User(null, null);
        user.setId(5);
        user.setName("spider");
        user.setPlatform("Mac"); 
        updateRecordToTable(user);

    ArrayList<User> userlists=new ArrayList<User>();

        userlists.add(new User("alish","Windows"));
        userlists.add(new User("galish","Ubundu"));
        userlists.add(new User("balish","Boss"));
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}

private static int updateRecordToTable(User user) throws SQLException 
{

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE NEWDB SET NAME =? , PLATFORM = ?  WHERE ID =? ";

    try 
    {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

        System.out.println("Record is updated all to NEWDB table!");

    }
```

Try to fix this program .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps

Comment: I don't see the usage of user parameter in updateRecordToTable method ?

Comment: you don't give any real values to your statement - only the query. Btw. `new User(null,null)` and then using setters cries for an additional constructor for User

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the parameters.

```
private static int updateRecordToTable(ArrayList<User> users) throws SQLException 
{
  int i = 0;
  Connection dbConnection = null;
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

  String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE NEWDB SET NAME =? , PLATFORM = ?  WHERE ID =? ";

try 
{
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    for (User user : users){
       preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
       preparedStatement .setString(1, user.getName());
       preparedStatement .setString(2, user.getPlatform());
       preparedStatement .setInt(3, user.getId());
       preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
       i++;
    }
    dbConnection.commit();

    System.out.println(i + " Records updated!");

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this code is more helpful. But Can't Updated all records.How to update all records using arraylist?

Comment: you have to change the arguments of your method from a single User to ArrayList<User> and use for example a for loop to iterate through tha ArrayList. I'll edit my previous answer to give you an example.